# Windows: return value from CMD to store as variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows CMD script which is processing files across many machines across our Wintel estate and feeds them into our SFTP Gateway.

The job takes multiple arguments to determine which files to process in a given directory.
When the job executes, it scans the directory(s) for files that match the regex %FM_PREF% (Filemase Prefix) and %FM_SUFF% (Filemask Suffix), and proceeds to store the "oldest" filename as a variable ("%FILE_IN_PROCESS")

This is acheived by the following:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d "%FM_PREF%"*."%FM_SUFF%"`) do set FILE_IN_PROCESS=%%f
```

It then checks that it can get an exclusive lock on the file by checking the %ERRORLEVEL% of the following:

```
echo.N|copy /-y NUL "%FILE_IN_PROCESS%" 1>NUL 2>NUL
```

The problem I've just encountered is that I've been asked to use this process to handle files on a print server, and the files that are being created contain spaces in the filename.

Not a big problem, as I can simply do this to rename the "%FILE_IN_PROCESS%" by donig this:

```
echo %FILE_IN_PROCESS% | find " " 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 cmd /e:on /v:on /c "for %f in ("%FILE_IN_PROCESS%") do (set "n=%~nxf" & set "n=!n: =_!" & ren "%~ff" "!n!" )"
```

The challenge is that I want the value of !n! to be returned to the parent process so that I can reset the %FILE_IN_PROCESS% variable to be the new filename (that has had the spaces converted to underscores)

I'm stuck... and being a Unix sysadmin for 20+ years, Windows/DOS/CMD files are not my area of expertise.

Is it possible to return a value back to the original job that spawned the "cmd /e......" command, or will I have to write a nasty work-around like creating a temporary file on disk and reading that back into the %FILE_IN_PROCESS% variable?

Advice appreciated ???

---

Answered by @jeb
I created a shortened version of the script called "dave.cmd"

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set FM_PREF=TNO_A4
set FM_SUFF=tno
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d "%FM_PREF%"*."%FM_SUFF%"`) do set FILE_IN_PROCESS=%%f
echo.
echo pre FILE_IN_PROCESS=%FILE_IN_PROCESS%
echo.
echo "%FILE_IN_PROCESS%" | find " " 1> NUL 2>NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  set "newName=!FILE_IN_PROCESS: =_!"
  ren "!FILE_IN_PROCESS!" "!newName!"
)
set FILE_IN_PROCESS=%newName%
echo post FILE_IN_PROCESS=%FILE_IN_PROCESS%
```

Then to show it worked:

```
C:\temp\space>date /t > "TNO_A4 a b c dave.tno"

C:\temp\space>.\dave.cmd

pre FILE_IN_PROCESS=TNO_A4 a b c dave.tno

post FILE_IN_PROCESS=TNO_A4_a_b_c_dave.tno

C:\temp\space>
```

Comment: It seems you're already familiar with how to do it.  Whenever you want to capture the output of any command, including the output of a batch script, use a `for /f` to execute the command you want to capture.  `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cmd /c batfile.bat') do set "FILE_IN_PROCESS=%%~I"`.  You're already doing it to capture the output of your `dir` command.  In your child batfile, simply echo whatever you want to pass back to the caller.

Comment: As an alternative you can create an additional file to store the wanted value in file name or content.  echo !n! > somePredefinedFile.mmm or echo SomeText>!n! and check the file in caller process after job execution.

Comment: thanks to both of you who added comments - I'd dipped my toe into both methods, but then (with my shell-scripting background) thought I could do things a different way and started spiralling out of control "aargh!"

Comment: You could install cygwin or msys and work the straight way with bash (and I am a batch nerd!)

Comment: @jeb - best & simplest answer - thank you!
This was also my first ever post to stackoverflow, and am immensely impressed to get educated responses so quickly - you've all restored my faith in the IT (teccie) community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why you need it at all?
You don't need to start a child cmd, you can do it in the same batch context.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  set "newName=!FILE_IN_PROCESS: =_!"
  ren "!FILE_IN_PROCESS!" "!newName!"
)
```

But then I wonder if you can just use the unmodified names?